# Casting from string to unsigned char* leaves garbage

Tags: c++, casting, arduino, unsigned-char

This is C++ newbie question. I have an Arduino sketch with following code to transmit bluetooth low energy UART notification.

When `command` is 5 characters I get the 5 characters at the bluetooth receiver side. However, when I follow a 5 character `command` with a single character command, what is received is the single character followed by last 3 characters from the previous `command`.

Example,

`command` is `-1,0t`. What I receive is `-1,0t`. But next `command` is just `r`. What I receive is `r,0t`.

What's happening here? How do I get just "r"?

```
int BLEsend(String command){
    byte length = sizeof(command);    
    unsigned char* notification = (unsigned char*) command.c_str(); // cast from string to unsigned char*
    Serial.print(length);
    BLE.sendData(UART_SEND, notification, length);
    Serial.print("Notification Sent: "); Serial.println(command);
    delay(100);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sizeof(command)` will *not* give you the length of the string. You need to use the [`length`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringLength) member function.

Comment: That WAS the problem! Thanks. Could you please write an answer, I'll accept it. (I feel like an idiot).

Answer (score 0):

[sizeof( )](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't give you the length of the string.

You can use `int length = command.length( );` instead.

Also `command.size( );` should work as well.

Comment: It's not just "old"; it contains a redundancy and a flaw. (a) You do not need to traverse a string to find its length when `std::string` already caches the length. So that approach is O(n) instead of O(1) - yikes! (b) Strings are binary safe but your `strlen` length-counting technique is not. ..... In short, there are _reasons_ that we abandoned those sorts of things long ago; we don't just do it because of the arbitrary passage of time. Besides, `strlen(someCString)` is "old" but `strlen(aCPlusPlusString.c_str())` was _always_ silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're right as always I removed it from my Answer :) better not teach this anymore

Answer (score 0):

you need also to copy the string `command.c_str()` to `notification` :

```
notification = new char[length + 1];
strcpy(notification , command.c_str());
```